# Показать значения HTML формы

Tags: simple-html-dom, php, html

Здравствуйте.

Пытаюсь показать значения HTML формы, их количество бывает разным.  
Вот к примеру :

```
    <select name="Size" id="Size" class="input" style="width:auto;">
            <option value="">Select Size</option>
            <option value="2">Small</option>
            <option value="3">Medium</option>
            <option value="4">Large</option>
    </select>
```

Надо вывести значения "Small","Medium","Large", и т.д., в виде

```
<select name="моя_форма" id="ид_формы" class="input">
        <option value="Small">Small</option>
        <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
        <option value="Large">Large</option>
</select>
```

Мой код :

```
<?php
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
$url = "http://сайт.ком";

$html = file_get_html($url);
    $option = $html->find('select#Size/option[value]');
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($option); $i++) {
        $element = $option[$i];
        $value = $element->value;
        $content = $element->innertext;
    }
?>
```

Теперь мне надо вывести (не все разом) по очереди эти option value и я не знаю как это делается потому-что я полный профан в PHP. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

[Документация](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) как правило содержит в себе много ответов на большинство вопросов.
[Больше здесь](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm)

Для данной ситуации можно воспользоваться следующим кодом

```
$output = '';

$form_name ='my-form-name';
$form_id = 'form-id';

foreach($html->find('select#Size') as $select) 
{
    $output = '<select name="'. $form_name .'" id="'. $form_id .'" class="input">';
    foreach($select->find('option') as $option) 
    {
        if ((int)$option->getAttribute('value') > 0) {
            $output .= '<option value="'. $option->getAttribute('value') .'">'. $option->plaintext .'</option>';
        }           
    }
    $output .= '</select>';
}

print $output;
```